# C++ using math.h for sin returns "too many arguments in function call"

Tags: c++

The user inputs a number, which is converted from characters to a double (the number is is 0.0 before input where it is updated to any number). I should then be able to convert this and find the sin value. At the moment I get an error "too many arguments in function call". I understand I need to convert the users input into radian but I can't seem to find a work around.

Here is a snippet of the code (my Pi and Logarithm functions work okay)

Using public as the function is accessed from another class.

I've looked at a lot of sources but here are two that helped:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/144006/

I know I'm missing something obvious but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
class calculations {
public: double sin()
{
    double radian = ((number1 * 180) / 2);
    result = sin(radian);
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that `public:` seem out of place for you?

Comment: @DeiDei I'm accessing it from another headerfile. All my other functions work okay when using Pi or logarithms. Should I not use public?

Comment: I looked at this; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/sin/ 
and this http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/144006/ for converting but I'm still getting the error

Comment: (C++ function declarations don't work that way, remove the `public:`)

Comment: public is a keyword that can only be used inside a class. What you have does not a class make.

Comment: sorry this is all in a class called calculations (its a long script and i didn't want to post it all)

Comment: How are you calling the function? My feeling is you need `number` to be a parameter, so your signature should be `double sin(double number1)`

Comment: so the user puts in their number and the the number is converted from a string to characters to a double (works fine for the other functions so hopefully its not this) then the boolean ensures the correction function is called in the script above (from the input script) So this is what the input script see's when it is called;
  else if (sin == true)
  {
   result = storage.sin();
   textinout->Text = "" + result;
   return result;
  }

Comment: sorry about the bad layout I'm new to stack overflow and I'm not sure if there's a better way to lay it out in comments

Comment: So if I add double sin(double number1) the calculations script (buisness logic) stops complaining but the problem is that number1 is converted to a double and declared within this script so the input script has too few arguments

Answer (score 2):

Change the call to `std::sin(radian)`. As written it's trying to call your `sin` function. Yours doesn't take any arguments, and it's being called with one argument, which is what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: Thank you so much! The error is gone! It's outputting wrong numbers but as least I can work on that now!

Comment: double sin()
{
 result = std::sin(number1);
 return result;
}
Now returns the correct result!